# how to use a datediff together with a count having statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to get the time it takes between 2 items before they are sold if that specific item had been sold more than 2 times and then how would I then be able to use the alias soldtime later for orderby

but I get this error:

> Column 'sales.InvoiceDetailItem.DateTimeCreated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 4
>   Column 'file.Item.DateTimeCreated' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

```
    SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DAY,PS.[DateTimeCreated],P.[DateTimeCreated]) AS 'SoldTime'
, p.[Name]
, PS.[ItemCode]
, COUNT(*)
FROM
[ISTABLocalDB].[file].[Item] P
inner join [sales].[InvoiceDetailItem] PS on P.[LastInvoice_ID] = PS.Invoice_ID  
GROUP BY
    p.[Name], PS.[ItemCode]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) >= 2
    order by p.[Name]
```

Comment: The error message explains the problem.  Your call to `DATEDIFF` is not an aggregate, meaning that each name/item code group might have _multiple_ diff values.  _Which_ value do you want?  You could take the max diff, for example, but you should edit your question and show some sample data.

Comment: I don't think you need the HAVING, because if an INNER JOIN occurs, there has to have been 2 sales.  If you only have 1 sale, then it has no LastInvoice_ID record to join to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DAY,MIN(PS.[DateTimeCreated]),MAX(P.[DateTimeCreated])) AS 'SoldTime'
, p.[Name]
, PS.[ItemCode]
, COUNT(*)
FROM
[ISTABLocalDB].[file].[Item] P
inner join [sales].[InvoiceDetailItem] PS on P.[LastInvoice_ID] = PS.Invoice_ID  
GROUP BY
    p.[Name], PS.[ItemCode]
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) >= 2
    order by p.[Name];
```

Answer (score 1):

you can select count( PS.[ItemCode]) 
why you are using '*' ?

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(DAY,PS.[DateTimeCreated],P.[DateTimeCreated]) AS 'SoldTime'
, p.[Name]
, PS.[ItemCode]
, count( PS.[ItemCode]) 
FROM
[ISTABLocalDB].[file].[Item] P
inner join [sales].[InvoiceDetailItem] PS on P.[LastInvoice_ID] = PS.Invoice_ID  
GROUP BY
    p.[Name], PS.[ItemCode]
HAVING 
    count( PS.[ItemCode])  >= 2
    order by p.[Name]
```